# MVC Framework that is similar to ASP.NET MVC but for Winform

Tags: c#

I know there are MVC for Winform (MVC# etc.) but if have to develop on ASP.NET MVC and then on Desktop I don't want to have 2 different frameworks so is there anything close to ASP.NET MVC but for Winform ?

What I mean is that the specific part of ASP.NET which is url routing for example should be replaced by something on winform so that one can readily switch from one platform to the other.

This seems rather common sense needs to me so why doesn't this seem to exist or taken into account at Microsoft ?

All focus seems to be on web development nowadays which I regret because there are many desktop apps in enterprise that have the same level of complexity as web app and would benefit from not reinventing the wheel and use a widely spread MVC framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Smart Client Software Factory (SCSF):

[An Introduction to the Smart Client Software Factory and Composite Application Block](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/07/14/an-introduction-to-the-smart-client-software-factory-and-composite-application-block-part-1-modules-and-shells/)

Comment: Seems great but seems not to be readily reusable with ASP.NET MVC without deep thinking ?